# how do I set image and text both in top tabbed bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs, uisegmentedcontrol, scrollable

I want a functionality similar to this image:

[image]

Top segment like tab bar is scrolling and it contains icons and title which are dynamic and upon selection, sub categories are also dynamic added in collection view from web-service. I have manages all things except icons before title in upper tab swipe.
Used this library to achieve all : [CarbonKit](https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit)

Anyone here know how do i add that icons with title text or any other third party controller I can use? Please suggest

Comment: you can use simpe UIbutton

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik you mean to say UIButtons on top and what if user scrolls from below pages? Adding more controllers is not a good idea.

Comment: choice and ideas is yours, if you not like the thirdparty, then do like , create one scrollview indise scroll on top add button with tags, below use tableview or progrmatically to access , thats all

Comment: @Nij Have you implement the Text with Image using CarbonKit ?

Comment: @Aashish1aug I achieved this functionality using **[YSLContainerViewController](https://github.com/y-hryk/YSLContainerViewController)** and modified library, removed their UILabel and placed UIImage myself.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But this can be achieve may be like bellow : https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit/issues/99

Answer (score 1):

i think it is custom segment controller . You can use this framework

https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

for making custom segment like this .

Comment: Yes it is custom segment and i want both icon and text, in carbon kit you can either use image or string for tab bar. Does HMSegmentControl provide both? I don't think so.

Comment: @nij you can use image which contain icon + text .

Comment: I also tried that but images have by default tint color and issue is still pending to resolve. See https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit/issues/100

Comment: in hmsegmentedcontrol you can provide selected and deselected state image . check example from github

Answer (score 1):

Well i had created a control for requirement similar to yours,

[image]

It is built using UICollectionView(for header) and UIPageViewController. I had created a basic cell for this and right now it is not customisable. Code is available on [Github](https://github.com/kishoretheju/KTMPageControl), you can give provision to use custom cell in that.